# wpf bind textbox to List - MainWindow.List.Item[0]

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textbox, updatesourcetrigger

I have a static List in my MainWindow. If changes occur, CurrValue is set immediately.

```
public static List<varVisu> varVisuListDll = new List<varVisu>();
```

In my class, there is a INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

```
    public string m_CurrValue;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string CurrValue
    {
        get { return m_CurrValue; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != m_CurrValue)
            {
                //set value
                m_CurrValue = value;
                //notify anyone who cares about it
                Notify("CurrValue");
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but now, I **want to bind a Textbox (Text) in Window#2 to the first item (varVisuListDll[0].CurrValue)** in this List.

How can I bind the TextBox.Text to this value (Text={Path, UpdateSourceTrigger ...}??

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtManualMode" Text="{Binding ElementName=????, Path=CurrValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I have tested with (dtgrVariables.ItemSource=MainWindow.varVisuListDll). This work's.

Please help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

I set a binding in code behind. That work's fine.

```
        varVisu v1 = MainWindow.varVisuListDll[1];
        txtManualMode.DataContext = v1;
        Binding binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("CurrValue") };
        txtManualMode.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense if you could as well write a simple binding expression in XAML, and make `varVisuListDll` a public property instead of a field. Is there anything in my answer that you didn't understand?

Comment: I understood. But in my case (in the next step), I have to set a variable(x) to a control(x). With code behind binding, I can dynamically map a variable to a control.

Answer (score 0):

`varVisuListDll` must be a property, not a field:

```
private static List<varVisu> varVisuListDll = new List<varVisu>();

public static List<varVisu> VarVisuListDll
{
    get { return varVisuListDll; }
}
```

Then the binding should look like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(local:MainWindow.VarVisuListDll)[0].CurrValue}"/>
```

Or, if you're using an older framework than .NET 4:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=[0].CurrValue,
                        Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.VarVisuListDll}}"/>
```